# What are the c++ commands for case speaker?

Tags: c++, c, case, midi

I'm trying to make a MIDI song using c++. What are the commands?

Comment: Not answerable. You need to include way more information, like OS, if you use an library and which (or why you don't), what you want to do exactly, why you can't read the documentation, etc.

Comment: Obviously the OP has no clue on what `C++` is.

Answer (score 2):

If your platform is just "C++", then there are no such "commands". The C++ standard does not specify sound at all.